# NativeScript Angular Basic app size on Android is > 160 MB

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Basic HelloWorld Nativescript-Angular app size > 160 MB when it is pushed to a android phone.
Basic HelloWorld Native-Android app size is < 4 MB when it is pushed to a android phone.

Why is Nativescript-Angular app is so big and what can be done to reduce its size..?

Steps to reproduce:

1. tns create HelloWorld --ng
2. Connect Phone
3. tns run android
4. Settings -> Search for "Application manager" -> Tap "Application Manager"
5. Tap HelloWorld application.
6. Tap storage to see the size of the app.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any devDependencies installed by mistake as dependencies, A common issue I am observing is that devs are using `tns-platform-declarations` as a dependency which is causing a greater output size for the build app. It should be installed as devDedepdency e.g. `npm i tns-platform-declarations --save-dev`

Comment: e.g this app is 15mb archived and 34MB after instalation https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nativescript.curiosity&hl=bg ..the repos is here https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos - of course the app is build with all optimizations (`tns run android --bundle --env.uglify --env.snapshot --env.aot --release <release-params-here>`)

Answer (score 2):

This is very much normal here as Native-script works with node_modules and while building app, it's dependency are added in build.

The NativeScript Android Runtime consists of several major parts that provide the core functionality. These include:

Аn embedded version of Google’s JavaScript virtual machine - V8 - to run JavaScript.
A C++ layer that tells V8 what to do with all the Android APIs.
A Java layer that performs the glue behind the native C++/JavaScript to Android APIs (and vice-versa).
The first two layers are native libraries (compiled to machine code) and they are CPU architecture dependent, a.k.a ABI (Application Binary Interface), unlike Java and JavaScript which are dynamically (JIT) compiled

To Optimize the perfomance and bundle size you can use the snapshot plugin. That is only for release buils.You need to provide the --env.snapshot flag along with the other release arguments:

```
tns build android --bundle --env.snapshot --release
```